# Function that's calculating a log - Unused variable error

Tags: c

I'm writing a function that tries to get the square of a root.
I guess it's easier with an example:

I want to give a number to that function, say 1024 and the function should tell me 12. So always looking for the x here: 1024 = 2^x. 
If I gave 255 to the function it should return 7.

Now I guess my maths is pretty okay, but I get an Error saying I didn't use a Variable in Line 6. Could you have a look?

```
int log_base2(int num)
{
  int x = 2;
  int count = 0;
  for(; x <= num; x * 2 )
  {
    count++;
  }

  return count;

}
```

Error is in line 6 ( for(....))

Comment: Classic: a grammatically correct text, followed by "sorry for my terrible English" ;)

Comment: It was not about the grammer, but rather the lack of vocabulary and the confusion if I use the right one. :)

Comment: 'x' is not being referenced inside the 'for' code block.  Suggest using 'while( x< num) { count++; x *=2; )'  also, the third parameter of the 'for' statement:  'x*2 does not increment x so the code would fail during execution, even if the compiler had not raised a warning.

Answer (score 6):

```
for(; x <= num; x * 2 )
```

Here `x * 2` calculates its value, and then throws the result out. What you want is probably:

```
for(; x <= num; x *= 2 )
```

The error message is perhaps because the compiler optimizes the variable `x` away as it's useless.

Comment: Oh sure, how could I oversee that *facepalm*
Thanks for your fast answer!

Comment: Thanks for the editing. Still pretty new here. :)

Comment: @Yíu; That's how you will learn.

Answer (score 4):

You are not modifying `x` anywhere. If you want `x` to become `2 * x` in the next iteration you have to change this

```
for(; x <= num; x * 2 )
```

to

```
for(; x <= num; x = 2 * x )
```

Comment: Oh sure *facepalm* . Thanks for clearing that up!